# LLVM IR to Executable Segfaults after Compilation

Tags: compilation, llvm, executable, llvm-ir

I'm currently in the throes of writing a **compiler** for a toy language; this is a new area for me. I'm using the **LLVM** C++ API to generate LLVM **IR** and from there, an object.

The issue comes (I think) with linking the object and being able to execute it.

---

I have `main.ll` comprised of the utter minimum IR I could come up with:

```
define void @main() {
  ret void
}
```

This runs just fine with `lli main.ll`, i.e. it does nothing.

I compile it to object format with: `llc --filetype=obj -o main.{o,ll}`.

And link to no existing library with: `ld.lld -o main{,.o}`

However **the resulting binary immediately segfaults**. I took the advice of a few tutorials which led me to try to link via GCC and I was informed that "[Relocations] can not be used when making a PIE object" which Wikipedia tells me refers to position independence in the resulting binary.

So I recompiled to object with: `llc --filetype=obj --relocation-model=pic main.{o,ll}` and recompiled with GCC and it worked, running the output did nothing as expected.

But running the `ld.lld` command again and attempting to run that binary, again, immediately segfaults.

So, the first question I had was: **what step am I missing between linked-object (assuming I'm  linking correctly) and binary for this simple example?**

Is there an `ld` flag I'm missing, some required library even if I'm not making use of any one in particular?

---

There are then more issues even with the GCC method when I try to link against libc to make use of `printf` in the IR but I think I need a better understanding of this simple example before attacking that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that finds this and is trying to make a `.ll` file into an executable: I've found that the C runtime libraries were what was missing. These are included by default by both `gcc` and `clang` but the `-v` options didn't give me much to go on sadly...

Using the [relocation model](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm_1_1Reloc.html) under LLVM of `PIC_` and linking the resulting object dynamically with the C runtime libs, I've managed to get the `.ll` file to run regularly.

An example command (obviously OS specific) would be:

```
ld --verbose -L/usr/lib -lc \
  -dynamic-linker \
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
  /usr/lib/Scrt1.o \
  /usr/lib/crti.o \
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtbeginS.o \
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtendS.o  \
  <object file> \
  -o <binary> \
  /usr/lib/crtn.o
```

I'm not 100% sure on the "why" of the matter aside of guessing, but this works and your standard `ld -L... -lc <object file>` does not.

If anyone can provide clarification, I will happily accept their answer.

Comment: The entry point of an executable is not `main` but `_start`. There is a deafult implementation of `_start` that will call `main` inside the crt (typically in crt0). So the addition of the crt objects has included the entry point for you which then calls your main.